# More efficient approach for finding pairs

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I recently came across a problem which stated to find the number of good pairs of circles. A good pair of circles is formed when a given distance can be obtained by joining any point *P1* on the first circle and *P2* on second one. We are given *N* circles and *Q* distances.  The next *N* lines contain the coordinates (*X*,*Y*) of a circle's center, along with its radius *R*.  After that, the next *Q* list the distances to check for.

The following constraints apply:

2 ≤ *N* ≤ 10<sup>3</sup>

1 ≤ *Q* ≤ 5⋅10<sup>5</sup>

*X*,*Y* ≤ |2⋅10<sup>5</sup>|

1 ≤ *R* ≤ 2⋅10<sup>5</sup>

0 ≤ *K* ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>

Execution time must be < 1 sec.

Here, *K* is the distance to check for.

*Removed my code as it's a part of an ongoing contest*

My code is only partially accepted, and I spent hours trying to find an efficient algorithm for this question. Can anyone please provide an efficient approach for this problem so that TLE gets sorted out?

Comment: Is this from the ongoing contest?

Comment: Note: unlike, say, Mathematics SE, StackOverflow does not support MathJax.

Comment: How can I use symbols then?

Comment: @SahilSilare, you have Unicode, Markdown, and HTML to work with.  I have made some edits that improve your question's readability.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!

Comment: Suggestions: (1) use ordinary multiplication, not `pow()`, to compute small integer powers, especially squares.  (2) Do not compute square roots at all; instead, compare squared distances.  Most of all, (3) read all the distances first and store them in an array, so that you can make the the loop over those the innermost one.  That will allow you to avoid redundantly repeating computations of inter-circle distances and overlap cases.

Comment: @JohnBollinger although these are good suggestions, OP likely needs a more efficient algorithm altogether

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, whereas I agree that the solution to performance problems, especially those encountered in online challenges such as this one, is usually to find a better algorithm, I don't see much room for improvement in that area here unless some key detail of the problem has been omitted (or unless you consider my suggestion (3) to qualify).  If you see a way to avoid evaluating each pair of circles against each proposed distance then I would be interested in hearing it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can't really think of a full solution either, it's just that usually the intended answers to these challenge questions are better in terms of time complexity than the naive approaches; making micro-optimizations typically does not get the candidate very far. I guess a partial improvement would be to sort the list of distances to check and perform binary search on it.

Comment: Good, @meowgoesthedog, I like it.  That presupposes my (3) as a prerequisite, of course, and it gets you from O(Q * N^2) down to O(log(Q) * N^2).

Comment: Maybe a sort-and-sweep approach would help to eliminate "bad" pairs early, but in the worst case where the input has dense clusters of circles, that would probably not be too helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible solution that I can think from the top of my mind:

- Iterate over each pair of circles (c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>) and calculate two values *(P.S (c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>) is not the same as (c<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>))*

  1. If c<sub>2</sub> lies completely inside c<sub>1</sub> then ignore this pair.
  2. *Value<sub>1</sub>* - The shortest distance between the circle c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub>, - which is *distance between their centers - r<sub>1</sub> - r<sub>2</sub>* for disjoint circles, *0* for intersecting circles and *r<sub>2</sub> - dist - r<sub>1</sub>* for cases where c<sub>1</sub> lies inside c<sub>2</sub>.
  3. *Value<sub>2</sub>* - Minimum value with which r<sub>1</sub> should be increased such that c<sub>1</sub> completely engulfs c<sub>2</sub> such that they don't intersect at all - which is *distance between their centers + r<sub>2</sub> - r<sub>1</sub>* for disjoint or intersecting circles and *dist + r2* for rest.
- This range [*Value<sub>1</sub>*, *Value<sub>2</sub>*] defines the quantity with which the radius of circle c<sub>1</sub> should be increased such that it intersects with c<sub>2</sub>, which in our case is defined by K. If K belongs to the range [*Value<sub>1</sub>*, *Value<sub>2</sub>*], then we can gaurantee that there will exits a point P<sub>1</sub> on c<sub>1</sub> and point P<sub>2</sub> on c<sub>2</sub> such that distance between them is K. This is because if we increment the radius of c<sub>1</sub> in that range, it will intersect with c<sub>2</sub>.
- The above operation will be of time-complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>). We can collect all the ranges from all possible pairs of circles and to answer any query we just need to check if there's a range in which the given K lies.
- To faciliate the query we can use a Binary Indexed Tree for storing our ranges wherein which we add +1 at index *Value<sub>1</sub>* and -1 at index (*Value<sub>2</sub> + 1)* for the Binary Indexed Tree and then for every query we check if read on index K is > 0. The enables us to return the answer for any query in O(log(K)). The cost of constructing the tree is O(N<sup>2</sup>log(K)) - inclusive of forming all pairs of circle.
- We can also use an auxiliary array instead of a Binary Indexed Tree to answer query in O(1), the scope of which I'm willing to discuss if required.

As for the auxiliary array approach, initialize an array of length K i.e. 10^6 with all elements initially set to 0. Now maintain a min heap of all Value<sub>1</sub> and another min heap of all the values Value<sub>2</sub>.
Now,

```
aux_array = [0, 0, ... ]
curVal = 0
for i in range(0, 10^6):
  while minHeapValue1.root() == i:
     curVal += 1
     minHeapValue1.rootPop()
  while minHeapValue2.root() == i:
     curVal -= 1
     minHeapValue2.rootPop()
  aux_array[i] = curVal
```

Now if aux_array[query_k_value] > 0, then it means there is a range which includes `query_k_value`, else not.

Hence the total time complexity of the problem is O(Qlog(K) + N<sup>2</sup>log(K)).

Comment: Can you provide an insight into the Auxillary array? I would be interested in knowing that.

Comment: In your second point, you've mentioned that iff K belongs to the range then we can guarantee that there exists a point P1 on circle C1 and P2 on circle C2 such that distance between them is K. But what if the circles are concentric? Like if we have circles with centers (0,0) and radii 5 and 10 then the range would be [-15,15] and for K=0 it satisfies which is wrong.

Comment: @SahilSilare I've updated my answer to cover corner cases and also added the solution using an auxiliary array. It's highly likely that I still might be missing out on something but this approach should give you a good head start at the moment. Cheers!

Comment: According to your conditions, I've already implemented the approach that you're stating, except that auxiliary array but again it's TLE.

Comment: @SahilSilare without the auxiliary array, the cost of answering each query will be O(N^2) which will not be sustainable.

Comment: @SahilSilare really great to hear! Glad I could be of help :) Do let me know about the corner cases I had missed out on.

Comment: No, you haven't missed any corner case it works completely fine.